# What is a fast sort algorithm for a very, very long array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I have been trying to sort an array with 2000 elements in ReactJS using JavaScript. The array looks like this:

```
data = [

         {
    index: 0,
    id: "404449",
    product_name: "ette",
    brand_name: "Dyrberg/Kern",
    base_price: "55.000",
    actual_price: "55.000",
    filename:
      "http://images.booztx.com/dyrbergkern/400x523/329679_ette_sg_crystal.jpg",
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    id: "414661",
    product_name: "braided mobile chain",
    brand_name: "Octopus",
    base_price: "44.900",
    actual_price: "44.900",
    filename: "http://images.booztx.com/octopus/400x523/SC09-750MU.jpg",
  },

       ]
```

I tried sorting it by base_price with Array.sort( ) of JavaScript, like this:

```
 data.sort((a, b) => {
     
      return parseFloat(a.base_price) - parseFloat(b.base_price);
    });
```

but since the array is very long, it has 2000 elements it takes a very long time to sort. It takes about 4 minutes. Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong, maybe calling the sort itself in some sort of loop. What you showed should take only a couple of milliseconds for 2000 elements. Maybe using the profiler would help to figure it out.

Comment: At a glance, the main performance problem here is that you are using `parseFloat()` inside of the comparison function

Comment: I tried it without parseFloat. It still takes too long

Comment: How did you implement that?

Comment: I just importd the entire JSON file of 2000 elements in my simple react app, and called data.sort( ) on click of a sort button

Comment: Yes technically the `parseFloat` may have the largest impact but _overall_ it is so fast that it doesn't matter. I created an array like you showed, with 2000 elements with random `base_price`s, and the sorting function your showed took 280μs (yes, _microseconds_) with `parseFloat` and 40μs without. Yes, that's a 7x difference, but still, it's less than a millisecond overall, so... So as said, you must have an issue somewhere else that's causing it to be so slow. Maybe you are rendering and rerendering tons of DOM element as well...

Comment: I tried it without parseFloat. It still takes a long time regardless. And I gave the JSON file to a friend and he tried it in his own app, it still takes a very long time

Comment: If the stringified length of the JSON is around few megabytes, you can run into memory issue, not sorting performance. You are probably conflating the two. As a minor improvement, try substituting parseFloat with `(+a || 0) - (+b || 0)`

Comment: Are the array and the objects inside it proxied in some way? Depending on how it is proxied, it could cause performance problems; try to make a non-reactive copy of the array, then sort that, instead, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: ...correction, it is approx. 10x what I wrote before (~3 milliseconds), I was accidentally resorting the already sorted array in tests. Still.

Comment: As you can see [here in the JSFiddle I made](https://jsfiddle.net/k3jt1aq5/), sorting takes only around 3ms (plus/minus, depending on your computer's speed of course). So, as already pointed out by me and others, it's probably something else slowing you (and your friend) down. Did you try using the JS profiler as I suggested? It will show you exactly what's taking the most computation time. See [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/) and [this](https://www.debugbear.com/blog/devtools-performance) for instructions.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin I don't think that's it - if all objects look like this, then 2000 elements will be 400-500KB, and parsing it is still very fast (takes 1-2ms on my machine)

Comment: @CherryDT I guess your test is close enough to [mine](https://jsbin.com/puvakuciya/1/edit?js,console). I'm only measuring one sorting iteration, so the result is probably higher. I'm getting 3-7 milliseconds. Repeatedly sorting a sorted array is probably going to take less time for later iterations which would bring the average down. Still, it just isn't anywhere *close* to what OP claims for performance, since sorting this 1000 times still takes something in the order of 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Subtracting 2 strings will implicitly parse them to numbers. So, `parseFloat` is not really required.

Comment: @VLAZ yes that was my mistake initially, I resorted the same array, that's how I got 0.3ms. But in the fiddle linked above I did it correctly and arrived at 3ms as well

Comment: @CherryDT ah, I missed that it was sorting different array. I'd still expect a slightly lower average because of JIT optimisation. And mine which only runs and sorts once might be showing too slow of a result, since it doesn't do a proper warmup. The real values in a real application might be closer to your measures. Still, the difference is so small and so far away from the 4 minutes that OP reports (if we take a runtime of 5ms, that's 48000 times difference) that I doubt the measures matter beyond proving that size isn't the problem.

Comment: turns out the problem was with the wrong usage of imports. I had imported the data as a constant, but array.sort( ) was trying to change it. I used a local variable for the result of sort and that fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, what you're describing should not actually take very long. Here's an example, and on my machine I'm seeing less than 10 milliseconds of runtime for a 2000 element array:

```js
const createFakeProduct = () => {
  const priceNumber = Math.random() * 100;
  const priceString = priceNumber.toFixed(3);
  return {
    index: 0,
    id: "12345",
    product_name: "hello world",
    brand_name: "foo",
    base_price: priceString,
    actual_price: priceString,
    filename: "abc123.jpg",
  }
}

const data = [];
const len = 2000;
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  data.push(createFakeProduct());
}


const before = Date.now();
data.sort((a, b) => {
  return parseFloat(a.base_price) - parseFloat(b.base_price);
});
console.log(`elapsed: ${Date.now() - before} milliseconds`);
```

There must be something additional thing besides what you've shared that's slowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was using imports incorrectly. I imported the data as a constant, but `array.sort( )` was trying to change it. I used a local variable for the result of `sort` and that fixed the problem.

```
import { data } from "assets/data/productList";

export const sortItems = (sortMode) => {
  const SoretdData = data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (sortMode === SortModes[1].type) {
      return parseFloat(a.base_price) - parseFloat(b.base_price);
    } else {
      return parseFloat(b.base_price) - parseFloat(a.base_price);
    }
  });
  return SoretdData;
};
```

Comment: Please don't summarize the solution in an answer. If you intend for this to be *the* selected answer then wait until the system times out and it will let you select it. I'd recommend reading "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" as proper formatting helps us read your response. Also, as said in "[ask]", grammar is important on SO. "`SoretdData`" should probably be "`SortedData`".